# Strange bug or am i mssing something?

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, loops

I am trying to insert elements into an array in ascending order, in order to achieve that i made the following code which works. But i would like to use "arrSize" instead of 10 here `for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)`  (below code works)

```cpp
int arr[9] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};
    int element = 7;
    int arrSize = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);
    int p = arrSize;
    for (; p && element < arr[p - 1]; --p) 
        arr[p] = arr[p - 1];
    arr[p] = element;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        cout << arr[i] << " ";
```

To do that i need to increment "arrSize", but when i do that my output is `1 2 3 4 5 6 7 7 8 10` (10 shouldn't be there, 9 should be there).
Please not that this happens even if i don't use "arrSize" instead of 10 like that (see below).

```cpp
int arr[9] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};
    int element = 7;
    int arrSize = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);
    int p = arrSize;
    for (; p && element < arr[p - 1]; --p) 
        arr[p] = arr[p - 1];
    arr[p] = element;
    arrSize++;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        cout << arr[i] << " ";
```

As you can see i don't use "sizeArr" after i increment but my program gives me wrong output that's why i referred to this as a bug.

Any reason why this is happening?

Thanks.

Comment: `arr[p] = arr[p - 1];` is UB on the very first loop iteration. You're accessing the element past the end of the array.

Comment: Arrays have fixed size. for insertion, you might use resizable container such as `std::vector`.

Comment: You can’t “insert” into a fixed size array …

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/fr97zGKE3

Comment: So the largest should just be dumped when inserting? if you only have 9 elements why do you print 10? I think you need to fix the off-by-one error for the initial value of `p`

Comment: There are two mistakes, first one mentioned above and second when printing array read outside buffer. Fixed: https://godbolt.org/z/4z8s1MT5s

Comment: @donkopotamus make sense thanks.

Comment: @Jarod42 my initial code that i used for my project was using ```new```  with a slightly different implementation using a temp container. And then i tried to re-do it without the temp. But i guess i forgot to use ```new``` ive been awake for long and dint really notice. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are writing past `arr[9]` in your code and probably overwrite other variables on the stack.

The valid indices in `arr[9]` are *0..8*. Everything else is *undefined behaviour*.

this:

```
int arrSize = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);
```

sets `arrSize` to *9*. And here:

```
int p = arrSize;
for (; p && element < arr[p - 1]; --p) 
   arr[p] = arr[p - 1];
```

You set `arr[9]` to `arr[8]`.

I can only guess what happens next, but since `element` is declared right after arr, there is a chance that this write changes `element` instead.

Also, you read 10 elements from arr in

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        cout << arr[i] << " ";
```

Comment: Thanks a lot this makes seance now. I should use a resizable container instead of an array as @jarod42 commented.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is off by one:

when you do `arr[p] = arr[p-1]` you are pushing the value to the right of the boundary of the array (outside of the memory allocated for array of 9 elements - with highest index of 8 - since you start with 0!).

When you do `arrSize++;` it does not reallocate the memory for the array, so you end up printing out all of the elements of the array and one additional value allocated in memory just after the array - in this case - value 10 (very likely it is the memory corresponding to `arrSize` (but it will depend on a particular situation and the compiler used).

In order to ensure you do not cross the boundary of allocated memory - ensure you either pre-allocate a larger one, or do not move items the the memory outside of it.